# Datatables to Charts.js to include hidden rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a dynamic table that is converted to DataTable. There are 8 columns and the user have options to generate 6 different charts that make use of different columns. Here is my table:

[image]

One of those charts is a line chart that compares cost based on Rent and Purchased using charts.

My current system loops the cost columns and builds the chart. However, that is only for currently visible records.

How do I address the issue?

Comment: how are you getting columns data?